# @angular/cdk drag and dop not working after import

Tags: angular, angular10, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a project using angular 10 and Bootstrap. I want to use the drag and drop feature offered by cdk without material.

I imported the lib

```
npm i @angular/cdk@9
```

I added in my root app.modules the lib

```
import {DragDropModule} from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DragDropModule
  ],
```

in my html file, I added this line

```
<div cdkDrop>
  <div class="box" cdkDrag>Drag me around!</div>
</div>
```

But nothing works, no error in console.

Please what is wrong with the process I have done ?

Thanks